# MySQL - Error In SQL Syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Kindly help me out. Here's the situation.

I have a cart where everything is working fine. The only thing is that I get error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND p.CatId = c.CatId AND ws.ProdId = p.ProdId' at line 1
```

Basically, what I am trying is to delete the single product from the cart, when there is only 1 product, by clicking on the button which is next to the quantity textbox. The product gets deleted from the cart, but throws the above mentioned error.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && $_SESSION['cart'] != "" ) {
        $total = 0;
        $subTotal = 0; $sbTotal = 0;
        $taxAmount = $tax = $totalTaxAmount = $taxAmt = 0;
        $cartWeightPerProduct = $totalCartWeight = $amtWeight = 0;

        $sql = "SELECT p.*, c.*, ws.* FROM products p, categories c, weight_shipping ws WHERE ProdCode IN (";
        foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value ) {
            $sql .= '"'.$id.'",';
        }
        $sql = substr( $sql, 0, -1 ) . ") AND p.CatId = c.CatId AND ws.ProdId = p.ProdId";
        if ($validate->Query($sql) == TRUE) {
            if ($validate->NumRows() >= 1) {
                while ( $row = $validate->FetchAllDatas() ) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td data-title="Product Image &amp; name" class="t_md_align_c"><img src="images/Products/'.$row['ProdCode'].'.jpg" alt="'.$row['ProdCode'].'" class="m_md_bottom_5 d_xs_block d_xs_centered" height="75" width="75"><a href="product.php?code='.$row['ProdCode'].'" class="d_inline_b m_left_5 color_dark">'.$row['ProdName'].'</a></td>';
                   echo '<td data-title="SKU">'.$row['ProdCode'].'</td>';
                   echo '<td data-title="Price"><p class="f_size_large color_dark">Rs. '.$row['ProdRate'].'</p></td>';
                   echo '<td data-title="Quantity"><div class="clearfix quantity r_corners d_inline_middle f_size_medium color_dark m_bottom_10"><form action="cart.php" method="POST"><input type="number" max="99" min="0" name="qnty['.$row["ProdCode"].']" value="'.$_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'].'" class="f_left"><br /><button type="submit" name="btnSubmit" class="f_left"><span class="fa fa-refresh"></span></button></form><form action="removeProduct.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="remove['.$row["ProdCode"].']" value="'.($row['ProdRate'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity']).'"><button type="submit" name="btnRemove" class="f_right"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button></form></div></td>';
                  $sbTotal = $row['ProdRate'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity'];
                  $subTotal = $sbTotal;
                  echo '<td data-title="Subtotal"><p class="f_size_large fw_medium scheme_color t_align_r">'.number_format($sbTotal, 2).'</p></td>';
                  $total += $subTotal;
                  $_SESSION['cartTotalAmount'] = $total;
                  $tax = $row['CatTaxPercent'];
                  $taxAmt = (($sbTotal * $tax ) / 100);
                  $taxAmount += $taxAmt;
                  $amt = 0;
                  $cartWeightPerProduct = ($row['weight'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['ProdCode']]['quantity']);
                  echo '</tr>';
                  $totalCartWeight += $cartWeightPerProduct;
              }
              $totalTaxAmount += $taxAmount;

              $_SESSION['cartWeight'] = $totalCartWeight;

              $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] = ($total + $totalTaxAmount);
              $_SESSION['Presentation']['TotalPayableAmount'] = $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'];
              if ( isset( $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'] ) ) {
                  $amt = $_SESSION['sessionTotalPayable'];
              } else {
                  $amt = "Rs. 0";
              }

              echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Cart Total:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'.number_format($total, 2).'</p></td></tr>';

              echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Taxes:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'. number_format($totalTaxAmount, 2) .'</p></td></tr>';

              echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Cart Weight:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'. $totalCartWeight .' grams</p></td></tr>';

              echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Shipment Fee </p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="f_size_large color_dark t_align_r" id="amt"><button id="amoutn" data-popup="#clickMeForGettingShippingAmount" class="tr_delay_hover r_corners button_type_16 f_size_medium bg_scheme_color color_light m_xs_bottom_5">Estimate</button></p></td></tr>';

              echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large t_align_r t_xs_align_c">Total Payable Amount:</p></td><td colspan="1"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large color_dark t_align_r">'.number_format(($total + $totalTaxAmount), 2).'</p></td></tr>';

              echo '<tr><td colspan="4"><div id="chckOutBtn"><button class="f_right tr_delay_hover r_corners button_type_16 f_size_medium bg_scheme_color color_light m_xs_bottom_5">Proceed to Checkout</button></div></td><td colspan="1"><p class="fw_medium f_size_large color_dark t_align_r"><a href="EmptyCart.php">Empty Cart</a></p></td></tr>';
          }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Your Cart Is Empty';
}
```

After [Jonathan Dahan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2634249/jonathan-dahan) comment, I have made the changes in `if` statement changing from:

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && $_SESSION['cart'] != "" ) {
```

to

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && is_array( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && sizeOf( $_SESSION['cart'] ) > 0 ) {
```

Comment: did you try printing out the whole sql select before executing it? aka `echo $sql;` ?

Comment: Yes, I did: here's the output of `$sql`: `SELECT p.*, c.*, ws.* FROM products p, categories c, weight_shipping ws WHERE ProdCode IN ("PROD-1539") AND p.CatId = c.CatId AND ws.ProdId = p.ProdId`

Comment: This error will happen if the $_SESSION['cart'] is empty, as it'll end up doing **... WHERE ProdCode IN () AND ...** which isn't valid syntax

Comment: @JonathanDahan This `foreach` loop is already inside the `if` statement checking the `$_SESSION['cart]` is set or not

Comment: I'd recheck, your if statement, because that's the only reason you'd end up with this error, can you post the code block with the if statement.

Comment: The last line of code shown should *append* to `$sql`, not *overwrite* it. Replace **`=`** with **`.=`**.

Comment: @JonathanDahan I have updated the question. have a look..

Comment: this doesn't tell you if the array is filled, it could be simply an empty array. `isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && $_SESSION['cart'] != ""` change it to be ... `isset( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && is_array( $_SESSION['cart'] ) && sizeOf( $_SESSION['cart'] ) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this like :

```
$ids = array_keys($_SESSION['cart']);

$sql = "SELECT p.*, c.*, ws.* FROM products p, categories c, weight_shipping ws WHERE ProdCode IN ('".implode("','",$ids)."') AND p.CatId = c.CatId AND ws.ProdId = p.ProdId";
```

Try it once..!!

Comment: the `$ids` are listed as strings not integers. your implode would need to reflect that. as of now it would be an error

Comment: I got this: `SELECT p.*, c.*, ws.* FROM products p, categories c, weight_shipping ws WHERE p.ProdCode IN (PROD-005045) AND p.CatId = c.CatId AND ws.ProdId = p.ProdId` `Unknown column 'PROD' in 'where clause'`

Comment: I have updated the query as per your condition @user3514160. Please try this..!!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if array has next element before add comma.

```
$iter = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($_SESSION['cart']));
foreach ($iter as $value) {
    $sql .= '"'.$id.'"';
    if ($iter->hasNext()) {
        $sql .= ",";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must dictate which table `ProdCode` would be getting like `p.ProdCode`
in

```
$sql = "SELECT p.*, c.*, ws.* FROM products p, categories c, weight_shipping ws WHERE p.ProdCode IN (";
foreach ( $_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value ) {
    $sql .= '"'.$id.'",';
}
$sql = substr( $sql, 0, -1 ) . ") AND p.CatId = c.CatId AND ws.ProdId = p.ProdId"; // Error Here
```